# Mongoose Schema Types | ES6 Symbols

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6, mongoose-schema, primitive-types

I've encountered a case where we're in need of storing `Symbol` objects in our db.
Is storing a [symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) in mongoDB (via Mongoose) feasible?

My gut feeling says that it isn't, but then - how can we share true enums across systems/platforms?

[Issue rises here I think:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)
 [image: Symbol]

Comment: The [BSON Type List is Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/). If it's not a BSON type then you are storing as `Binary` or a `String`. You can store just about anything that way, it's just than you cannot do meaningful queries on the data as with the supported BSON types themselves.

Comment: @NeilLunn - well, there's some thing I don't understand (and maybe you could help me). AFAIK, `Symbol`s are new primitives in ES6. How come they appear as `Deprecated` in the BSON docs?

Comment: Well `Map` is new as well, but **"It's not a BSON Type"**. You can only actually store what is defined as a BSON Type. Otherwise it's `Binary` or a `String`. Try to understand again.

Comment: The whole point of symbols is that they are unique in-memory primitives in a JS engine. If you are finding a case where you want to store a symbol-keyed value, that is probably a good sign that it shouldn't be symbol-keyed in the first place.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - ok, and what about Enums?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? JS doesn't have enums.